# Как реализовать фигурную линию в резиновой верстке

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно такое реализовать при резиновой верстке?

[image]

Спасибо.

Comment: Объясните, кривая должна растягиваться? Кружки закреплены на кривой?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Причем, кружки находятся в центрированном блоке шириной 60% от окна браузера, а линия проходит через всю ширину экрана.

Comment: @Astor ща намутим ;)

Comment: @lampa, супер! Заранее спасибо. 

Сочтемся.

Comment: @lampa, да, и если важно, то данные кружки находятся в дивах с float: left;

Comment: Хм, график синусоиды ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если честно, то я старался, но увы :D, как у вас на картинке не вышло, ибо займет очень много времени.

Да, реализовано кривыми [Безье](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%F0%E8%E2%E0%FF_%C1%E5%E7%FC%E5), и сама общая кривая состоит из нескольких частей.

Вот картинка для понимания, как вообще происходило строение:
[image]

Как видно, метод [bezierCurveTo()](https://www.xiper.net/manuals/canvas/2D-api/bezierCurveTo.html) позволяет прорисовать только одну кривую Безье, по этому пришлось сделать несколько кривых (может быть я и не прав).

В общем вот отладочный код, который выше на скриншоте: http://pastebin.com/fkRtBvA8

Вот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/Fw5Q9/

И собственно сам код:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<style>
html, body {
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
}
#worker {
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.block {
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

</style>

<script>
$(function() {
    var $worker = $('#worker')
    ,   $canvas = $('#picture')
    ,   ctx = $canvas[0].getContext('2d');
    

    
    
    function onResize() {
    
        
        var width = $worker.width();
        var height =  $worker.height();
        
        $canvas.attr({'width': width, 'height': height});
        
        /**
         * all ok
         */

        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
            
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0.1*height);
        
        
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(
            0, 0.1*height,
            0.02*width, 0,
            0.05*width, 0
        );
        
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(
            0.05*width, 0,
            0.11*width, 0,
            0.15*width, 0.5*height
        );
            
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(
            0.15*width, 0.5*height,
            0.186*width, height,
            0.3*width, height
        );
            
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(
            0.3*width, height,
            0.38*width, 1*height,
            0.4*width, 0.7*height
        );
            
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(
            0.4*width, 0.7*height,
            0.43*width, 0.3*height,
            0.5*width, 0.3*height
        );
        
        /**
         *
         */
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(
            0.5*width, 0.3*height,
            0.57*width, 0.3*height,
            0.6*width, 0.7*height
        );      
        
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(
            0.6*width, 0.7*height,
            0.62*width, 1*height,
            0.7*width, 1*height
        );
    
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(
            0.7*width, 1*height,
            0.814*width, 1*height,
            0.85*width, 0.5*height
        );
        
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(
            0.85*width, 0.5*height,
            0.89*width, 0,
            0.95*width, 0
        );
        
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(
            0.95*width, 0,
            0.98*width, 0,
            width, 0.1*height
        );
        
        ctx.stroke();
        
        return onResize;
    }
    
    function arc(ctx, x, y) {
        ctx.strokeStyle="#999";
        ctx.fillStyle="blue";
        ctx.arc(x-1,y,1, 0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    $(window).resize(onResize());
});

</script>


<div id='worker'>
    <canvas id="picture" style='position: absolute'></canvas>
    <table width=100% height=100%>
        <td width=16% align='right'>
            <div class='block'></div>
        </td>
        <td width=34%>
            <div class='block' style='margin-left: 75%'></div>
        </td>
        <td width=34%>
            <div class='block' style='margin-left: 20%'></div>
        </td>
        <td width=16% align='left'>
            <div class='block'></div>
        </td>
    </table>
</div>
```

Алсо, вам придется попотеть, находя идеальные значения для каждой кривой.

Я делал всё на листочке:

[image]

Но потом понял, что расчеты получились кривые и сохранить пропорции не получится, а переделывать уже не было времени.

Comment: @lampa, Вы волшебник! Спасибо.

Comment: @Astor хех, но я посоветовал прибегать к канвасу на сайте в последний момент. Куда лучше просто заново продумать элемент. Например, сделать задний повторяющийся фон, чем экспериментировать :)

Comment: То есть? не совсем понял о чем Вы... Разве это возможно реализовать без canvas? Ума не приложу как ...

Comment: @Astor я о том, что было бы проще сделать волну обычной фоновой картинкой, которая просто повторялась. Но то, что вы хотели, можно реализовать либо с помощью canvas'a, либо растяжением картинки - но тут все вытекающие недостатки.

Comment: А, понял. Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Да ладно — все. А border-radius что мешает использовать?

Answer (score 4):

Вот мой вариант с использованием нескольких фигур, образующих волну своими границами:

http://bars.koding.com/test/wave.html

Этот вариант вполне подходит в случае появления кнопок (красных кружков) в местах перетекания одной дуги в другую: они скрывают несостыковки. Еще правильнее было бы, наверное, svg использовать.

Comment: @Bars, спасибо! 

Вы тоже волшебник! +1

Comment: А в случае, если круги в отцентрованном блоке = 60%, при чем каждый круг в своем диве ... то как?

Comment: Круги центрованы по горизонтали? Никак. Я делал с условием что круги должны находиться на самой линии, то есть, их положение зависит от линии. А вы говорите, что нужно линию подстраивать под кнопки. То есть, нужно сначала как-то растянуть кривую (резиновая же), потом каким-то образом подстроить ее таким образом, чтоб она проходила через все 4 точки, которые, в свою очередь, лежат на одной прямой.

Я бы тогда посоветовал сформулировать условие нормально. А вот с дивами все просто: заменяете `a` на `div` и творите там что угодно, ведь, даже высота каждой кнопки определена.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо

Comment: @Bars браво!

Answer (score 0):

Можно нарисовать SVG и растягивать ее на всю ширину. А иконки располагать используя flex-box модель.

PS: Чтобы не быть голословным, набросал прототип http://goo.gl/czCEj .
Работает только под WebKit, под другие браузеры делать лень.